# Random hidden value in Drupal form

Tags: drupal-7

I am developing simple guestbook module for one of my customers and as a spam prevention I decided to use an array of simple questions. For this I have to pick random question from the array and set the ID of this question (array element ID) in form so I can check the answer in submit handler. The problem is that the form is regenerated before the submit handler is evaluated so the random value changes.

Shortly: I am getting other value of `$form_state['values']['queston_id']` in submit handler function that it is in form. Why is that and how can I change this?

Thanks a lot!

This is my module:

```php
function gb_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['gb'] = array(
    'title' => t('Guestbook'),
    'description' => t('Guestbook page'),
    'page callback' => 'gb_guestbook',
    //'page arguments' => array('gb_guestbook'),
    'access arguments' => array('view guestbook'),
  );

  return $items;
}

function gb_guestbook() {
  dpm('generating page');
  $page = NULL;

  $page .= drupal_render(drupal_get_form('gb_guestbook_form'));

  $page .= 'list of guestbook messages here';
  return $page;
}

function gb_guestbook_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#description' => t('Please, enter your name.'),
  );

  $form['message'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#cols' => 5,
    '#title' => t('Message'),
    '#description' => t('Please, enter your message.'),
  );

  $questions = gb_get_question();
  $question_id = rand(0, count($questions)-1);
  $question = $questions[$question_id];

  $form['question_id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $question_id,
  );

  $form['spam'] = array(
    '#title' => $question['question'],
    '#description' => t('Please, answer the simple question so we know that you are a human.'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function gb_guestbook_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // spam check
  $values = $form_state['values'];

  $questions = gb_get_question();
  $answers = $questions[$values['question_id']]['answers'];
  if (!in_array(strtolower($values['spam']), $answers)) {
    drupal_set_message(t('You did not reply the answer correctly. Are you sure it was not typo?'), 'error');
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('Thanks for the contribution!'), 'status'); 
    // processing input
  }
}

function gb_get_question() {
return array(
  array (
    'question' => t('What is the capital of Slovakia?'),
    'answers' => array('bratislava'),
  ),
  array (
    'question' => t('What is the name of this band?'),
    'answers'=> array('divozel'),
  ),
  array (
    'question' => t('What is the biggest town in east part of Slovakia?'),
    'answers' => array('košice','kosice'),
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do this check in gb_guestbook_form_VALIDATE instead.

Comment: Very good point, thanks, unfortunately, it did not help. I have added a validate function and the behaviour is still the same. I have put debug output at the begining of _form function and _validate function. Form is generated before _validate function is called, so the question_id gets regenerated/randomized again, so the question_id which comes into the _validate function may not be the same as the one which was in the original form.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in a validation hook.  Also another issue in the function gb_guestbook_form_submit

You get the questions but not the answers array and then you are trying to compare them.  This could also be the source of your issue, you capture questions but not answers and then compare to the empty array of answers.

Comment: Yes, as I stated above, I agree it should be done in validation hook but the result is the same. I also changed the code, I am sorry I copied wrong version. The problem is that form is being generated **before** validation runs, so the `question_id` is being randomized again.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your random question generator in a conditional statement that checks if your question has been defined in the form yet.

```
$question_id = NULL;
$questions = gb_get_question();
if (!isset($form['question_id'])) {
  $question_id = rand(0, count($questions)-1);
}
else {
    $question_id = $form['question_id']['#value'];
}
$question = $questions[$question_id];
```

Comment: Also not good, because `$form['question_id']` is never set (at the place where I put it, it means right before the `question_id` element is created in the form), so the `$question_id` gets randomized again.

Comment: Well of course you still need to set $form['question_id']. I noted this is just the question generator logic. Add your $form['question_id'] as it was below this question generator logic and you should be set. Have you tried this code or are you just commenting on it? I have one more approach I could put in another answer.

Comment: This logic is still on the same place in the code and I did not deleted nor commented out the `$form['question_id']` bit. But because the logic goes **before** the `$form['question_id']` is set, there is no such array key in the `$form` variable, only `$form['name']` and `$form['message']`. I put the `dpm()` message there so I saw it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why my other answer isn't working for you, but here's another approach. The idea would be to store the question id in $form_state['storage'].

First, correct your form declaration so it passes in $form_state as a reference.

`function gb_guestbook_form($form, &$form_state) {`

Now check the $form_state['storage'] array for your question id, and set it if you haven't already, before you set the form value question_id.

```
$questions = gb_get_question();
if (!isset($form_state['storage']['question_id'])) {
  $form_state['storage']['question_id'] = array_rand($questions);
}

$form['question_id'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden',
  '#value' => $form_state['storage']['question_id'],
);
```

Comment: Declaration is fine in my code, `$form_state` is passed as a reference, I copied the wrong version of code, thanks for pointing out. Thanks for another suggestion, but this is the same problem all over again. No matter how or where you set the random ID, the _form handler is called before _validation and _submit, so the ID is being randomized again. In other words - _form callback is called before the _validate and the `$form_state['storage']` is not set. I do not know why, it probably should be, but it is not.

Comment: I would then try updating hook_menu() to go to the form directly, of nothing else, for troubleshooting: `'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form'` and `'page arguments' => array('gb_guestbook_form')` . Then make sure to clear menu cache. It would just be a more direct way of calling the form and rule out the possibility of embedding the form in a page callback out of the way. You definitely got something getting in the way of form building. Another possibility would be a form_alter() somewhere else in your code messing up your $form array?

Comment: Thanks mate, I really appreciate your effort. I have tried that as well (actually, that was the original way). I have solved this temporarily by using `$_POST` for checking the submitted values and if the question_id is being sent or not, so it works, but I would like to know the Drupal way anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem (and mine) is describe here:
http://www.sparklepod.com/myblog/drupal-form-same-form-for-build-and-validation/

In short. On submit the form is rebuild before the validation code is run. For me the solutions in the blog is not working for my Drupal 7 site.

What I have done is added the following line to the forum build:

```
$form_state['cache'] = true;
```

That will cache the form and the on _submit I will set it to false.